# Error while trying to access the validation error in Thymleaf form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is there any rules for naming of the attributes , setters and getters ?
I have a model class that has `String` attribute named `uuid` and setter and getter `setUUID(String uuid)` `getUUID()`
but when trying to validate on the input with Thymleaf to display an error if exist it crashes
**Note :** the `deviceName` attribute working perfectly

Following is my snippets of code:

**The Model**

```
@Entity
public class Device {

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String uuid;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String deviceName;

    public String getUUID() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUUID(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }
}
```

**The Form**

```
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/devices/save}" th:object="${device}">
    <input th:field="*{UUID}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('*{UUID}')} ?'border-danger'" type="text" name="uuid">
    <input th:field="*{deviceName}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('deviceName')} ?'border-danger'" type="text" name="deviceName">
</form>
```

> Error when trying to parse the template
>   An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/Devices/add-device.html]")
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/Devices/add-device.html]")
>       at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
>       at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
>       at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
>       at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
>       at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('uuid')" (template: "Devices/add-device" - line 28, col 87)
>       at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
>       at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
>       at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
>       ... 88 more
>   Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('uuid')" (template: "Devices/add-device" - line 28, col 87)
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
>       at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
>       at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
>       at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
>       at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
>       at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
>       at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
>       at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
>       ... 90 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'uuid' of bean class [com.logica.eguestbookservice.Models.Device]: Bean property 'uuid' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
>       at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:129)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
>       ... 113 more

Comment: The error / stacktrace doesn't match your code. Your attribute is named `UUID` not `uuid` the latter is the name of the field, not the name of the property. Name of the property is identified through the getter/setter.

Comment: thats why I couldn't solve it because I don't understand why it wants the attribute to be `uuid`

Comment: It doesn't. As stated your code doesn't match the error. You should use `UUID` as that is the name of the property.

Comment: The code in the Model has String `uuid` but the setter function is `setUUID()` that was the problem but thanks to @Wim I solved it by changing the setter name to `setUuid()`

Comment: How your field is named doesn't matter, the name of the getter/setter matters as that is the name of the property. The field could be named `foo` if you have a `setUuid` the property is named `uuid` and not `foo`. So `UUID` should work as well as that is derived from the getter/setter. But as mentioned what you posted asa form doesn't match the error. The naming of properties is defined in the Java Bean Specification (See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

Comment: I think that `*{UUID}` replaced `hasErrors('*{UUID}')` with`hasErrors('uuid')` like in the error

Comment: Why even use `*{UUID}` instead of just `UUID` ? Like the `deviceName`?

Comment: while I was playing around trying to fix it I had also `th:errors='*{UUID}'` that wasn't working then, not displaying any thing even the error was exist with name `'uuid'` which is the field name

Comment: and using just `UUID` wasn't working cause I couldn't select the error but wasn't throwing any exception as well

Comment: The main problem is that the validation uses the field it it defined on, and thymeleaf the properties (i.e. the getter). So the generated error was tied to `uuid` and not `UUID`. This is the drawback of validation part here and not following the java bean specificiation.

Comment: I was trying to do both at the same time so I wasn't able to define where was the problem you comments helped me a lot also I still can't get the error using either `uuid` or `UUID` while keeping the getters the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf is most likely following the JavaBean specification, so you would need to name your methods `getUuid()` and `setUuid` and change the form to:

```
<input th:field="*{uuid}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('*{uuid}')} ?'border-danger'" type="text" name="uuid">
```

Comment: It works fine like this but what if I want to set the setter method name as I wanted like `setUUID()` ?

Comment: and also where I can find the specifications related to those naming schemas ?

Comment: See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#variables which states "In Spring MVC-enabled applications OGNL will be replaced with SpringEL, but its syntax is very similar to that of OGNL (actually, exactly the same for most common cases)." https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions has more info on SpringEL.